# FMDB set up a collation sqlite3_create_collation

Tags: sqlite, collation, fmdb

I'm trying to do a search into my app BBDD that contains accented words.
My goal is to achieve searches with and without the accent.

I.E.

If I search for: "Introducción"

I would like get results with "Introducción" and "Introduccion".

I've read that I could accomplish this setting up a new collation but I cant find how do it.
It's possible?

In other post I've read it said that I should to create a new LIKE function, but again, I don't know how can do it.

If someone could help me, I'd appreciate it very much.
Thanks!